# Cuando asigno memoria a un struct de structs, ¿debo hacerlo para cada uno de sus atributos o solo para el contenedor?

Tags: c

Me surge la siguiente duda.
Tengo la siguiente estructura

```
typedef struct {
    tPilaStackNode *first;
} tPilaStack;
```

Que como veis, tiene la siguiente estructura

```
typedef struct tNode {
    tPila e;
    struct tNode *next;
} tPilaStackNode;
```

Que a su vez contiene la siguiente estructura:

```
typedef struct {
    tElement element;    
} tPila;
```

*(Como podéis observar no se queda ahí, sin embargo para mi ejemplo basta con esto)*

Como observo, se el elemento principal se trata de una pila, por tanto lo que quiero es crear una función que añada un elemento a la pila, es decir, un push.

```
PilaStack_push(tPilaStack *stack, tPila Pila) {

}
```

Mi duda es la siguiente: tengo que asignar memoria por cada struct que se contiene, es decir:

```
stack=(struct tPilaStack*)malloc(sizeof(struct tPilaStack))
stack->first=(struct tPilaStack*)malloc(sizeof(struct tPilaStack))
stack->first->next = (struct tNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tNode));
```

¿O basta con hacerlo para algún nivel en concreto?

Comment: Tienes que asignar espacio sólo para el contenedor. Pero si el contenedor contiene punteros, estos punteros quedarán apuntando a "no se sabe donde". Es costumbre usar `memset()` para rellenar con ceros la estructura retornada por `malloc()` (o bien usar `calloc()`) para asegurarse de que los posibles punteros que contenga sean `NULL`. Naturalmente en algún momento estos punteros deberán apuntar a algún lugar válido y entonces tendrás que reservar de nuevo memoria para el dato _al que apuntan_ (pero no para el propio puntero que ya tiene espacio reservado en la estructura)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como bien comentas, la memoria se reserva con malloc tal que:

```
puntero = (struct tipo*)malloc(sizeof(struct tipo));
```

Es decir la cantidad de bytes reservados dependerá del valor devuelto por `sizeof()`.

Pues bien, si tenemos una estructura tal que:

```
struct datos
{
  int dato1;
  int dato2;
};
```

E imprimimos su tamaño:

```
printf("%d", sizeof(struct datos));
```

Nos devolverá, típicamente 8, es decir, 4 bytes correspondientes a `dato1` y otros 4 corrrespondientes a `dato2`.

Ahora vamos a crear una segunda estructura que contenga la primera:

```
struct datosAvanzados
{
  struct datos datos;
  int otrosDatos;
};

printf("%d", sizeof(struct datosAvanzados);
```

Ahora `sizeof()` devolverá 12, es decir, 4 bytes por cada `int`. **Las estructuras anidadas incrementan el tamaño de la reserva**.

Si ahora creamos una segunda estructura apuntando a la primera:

```
struct punteroADatos
{
  struct datos* ptr;
};

printf("%d", sizeof(struct punteroADatos);
```

Vemos que ahora nos imprime 4 (si estamos en 32 bits) u 8 (64 bits). Es decir, **al usar punteros, reservas espacio únicamente para almacenar una dirección de memoria**.

Es decir, al reservar memoria únicamente tienes que preocuparte por los punteros, ya que los mismos se quedarán apuntando *a posiciones aleatorias*. Esto se puede solucionar reemplazando `malloc` por `calloc`. El resto de variables, por muchos niveles de anidamiento que tengas, tendrán asignada su propia dirección de memoria.

Answer (score 2):

> > Cuando asigno memoria a un struct de structs, ¿debo hacerlo para cada uno de sus atributos o solo para el contenedor?

Solo debes asignar memoria con `malloc` para el nodo (es decir, para la estructura `tNode`).

**1. Estructura:**

Debemos preocuparnos únicamente en reservar memoria con `malloc` para esta estructura (`tNode)`. Al puntero/miembro `next` no necesitas asignarle memoria, pero si se debe tener una referencia (dirección base) del nodo siguiente.

```
typedef struct tNode {
    tPila e;
    struct tNode *next;
} tPilaStackNode;
```

**2. Estructura:**

La estructura `tPila` tampoco se necesita reservar memoria con `malloc`, puede ser definido como una variable local y asignar el respectivo dato al miembro que tenga la estructura anidada `tElement`.

```
typedef struct {
    tElement element;    
} tPila;
```

**3. Estructura:**

La estructura `tPilaStack` no necesita ser creado en memoria con `malloc`, puede estar definido como una simple variable local (tendrá un almacenamiento automático, se crea cuando la función se invoque y se libera cuando la subrutina termine de ejecutarse), lo que si debemos tener en cuenta, es el miembro `first`. El puntero `first` debe tener la dirección de memoria del primer atributo/miembro del último nodo. Así que si este puntero no tiene una referencia que sea válida, tendrás problemas en tiempo de ejecución. Del contenido que tenga `first`, dependerá el recorrido de cada nodo de la pila.

```
typedef struct {
    tPilaStackNode *first;
} tPilaStack;
```

> > Como observo, se el elemento principal se trata de una pila, por tanto lo que quiero es crear una función que añada un elemento a la pila, es decir, un push.

```
PilaStack_push(tPilaStack *stack, tPila Pila) {

}
```

Una posible implementación para la función `PilaStack_push` sería:

```
tPilaStackNode* PilaStack_push(tPilaStack *stack, tPila Pila)
{
    tPilaStackNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(tPilaStackNode));
    if(newNode == NULL)
        return NULL;
    newNode->e.element.data = Pila.element.data;
    newNode->next = stack->first;
    stack->first = newNode;
    return newNode;
}
```

Centrémonos en los parámetros `stack` y `Pila`. Ambos parámetros se le puede pasar una variable de estructura con almacenamiento automático o estático, no necesariamente debe ser dinámico.

Llamaríamos la función de esta manera:

```
int main(void)
{
    tPilaStack stack = {NULL};
    tPila pila = {10};
    PilaStack_push(&stack, pila);
    free(stack.first);
    return 0;
}
```

**Funcionamiento:**

- Asignamos al miembro `first` (de la estructura `tPilaStack`) un valor por defecto, o sea, `NULL` (hay que acordarse que la pila debe tener un nodo con un miembro apuntando a `NULL` para definir un inicio y fin en la pila).
- Asignamos el valor de `10` al miembro que tenga la estructura anidada `tElement`.
- Por último, pasamos la dirección base de la estructura `tPilaStack` al primer parámetro y al segundo, pasamos la copia del contenido de la estructura `tPila`.

Si te das cuenta, no tuve que reservar memoria directamente con `malloc` a ningún miembro.